# In search of a function satisfying certain conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am searching for an example to illustrate a result but unfortunately I haven't been able to find any.

I need a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that:

- $f\in C^2$,
- $f,f',f''$ are bounded,
- $f$ is bounded away from $0$,

such that  $\Lambda(\cdot)$ and $\Lambda^{-1}(\cdot)$, the primitive of $1/f$ and its inverse respectively can be obtained explicitly.
This problem arises when considering ODEs of the form $\dot X=f(X)$.

I thought of letting $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}+1$  and then $\Lambda(x)=x-\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}$, but in this case $\Lambda^{-1}$ can not be obtain in term of elementary functions.

If you know of some example or some reference that presents examples of non-linear ODEs that can be solved explicitly please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f=1$ works....

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich well, yes you are right, although it is not really interesting for what I want to do

Comment: Of course it's not interesting. When there's a dumb counterexample like this it often indicates you haven't got the question straight yet - you might try to figure out what conditions you can add to the question to rule out this silly example